# Plot long and short drawn

Tags: pine-script, indicator

to plot long and short drawn automatically I wrote the following script.

But I cannot to insert a % to fix value of TP and SL.
I wish to fix:

- Take profit = the entry point value + 5% if it is long, and
- Stop loss = entry point -5%,
- and the same logic with stop loss

How do u change to get it?

```
if (longsignal)
    strategy.entry(" ", strategy.long)

if (shortsignal)
    strategy.entry(" ", strategy.short)
// random entry condition
moneyToSLPoints(money) =>
    strategy.position_size !=0 ? (money / syminfo.pointvalue / math.abs(strategy.position_size)) / syminfo.mintick : na    

p = moneyToSLPoints(input(300, title = "Take Profit $$"))
l = moneyToSLPoints(input(300, title = "Stop Loss $$"))

strategy.exit("x", profit = p, loss = l)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strategy.position_avg_price` to calculate the TP and SL prices. Then use the `limit` and `stop` arguments of the `strategy.exit()`.

```
long_tp_price = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + tp_percentage)
long_sl_price = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - sl_percentage)
short_tp_price = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - tp_percentage)
short_sl_price = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + sl_percentage)

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("Long Exit", stop=long_sl_price, limit=long_tp_price)

if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.exit("Short Exit", stop=short_sl_price, limit=short_tp_price)
```